# Summing a Geometric Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

The 'bouncing ball' question shows up a number of times but I've not found this variation on it:

In a section on geometric progressions we're asked to use the following formula:
$S=\frac{a(1-r^{n+1})}{1-r}$ to solve:

> A golf ball is dropped from a height of 81 inches. If it always
>   rebounds 2/3 of the distance it falls, use the formula to find the
>   total distance it has traveled if it caught at the top of the fourth
>   bounce.

I've managed to construct the series by hand as:
$81+2\cdot81(2/3)^1+2\cdot81(2/3)^2+2\cdot81(2/3)^3+81(2/3)^4$

I'm struggling to determine the values for $a, r, n$. Specifically, I can't figure out how to account for the need to double 81 in $81\cdot(2/3)^r$ and also how to account for not including the final drop (since the series needs to end at the top of the fourth drop).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may find it easiest to add 2 geometric series. 1 for the upward movements, and 1 for the downward. They will have different start and end points

Answer (score 0):

Closing the loop on this...

I took @Mathmo123 suggestion and did the following:

$
S=\frac{a(1-r^{n+1})}{1-r}    
$

where $S_1$ with $a=81, r=2/3, n=3$ gives 195 and $S_2$ where $a=81(2/3), r=2/3, n=3$ gives 130.

$S_1 + S_2 = 325$